# Angular 2 TypeScript distinct filtering nested data

Tags: json, typescript, nested, filtering

I'm wondering how to filter nested data in TypeScript and get distinct values.

I'm trying to get the country names: `long_name` as distinct values where `types[0] == "country"`

I can do it writing 3 `For` loops and 2 `If` statements but I have no clue in how to do it in an easier way by `.filter()` or `.find()`, can someone help me out?

I would need a `LINQ` alike statement to select all the country names (`long_name`) where `types[0] == "country"`.

this is the data:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
getAllCountries(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.getAll()
            .map((countries: any[]) => countries.filter(c => c.address_components.some(nestedObj => nestedObj.types.indexOf("country") >= 0)));
}
```

What I get now is all the objects that pass the the filter condition. I need to grab / map these country names (`long_name`) now to a distinct array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I might be stupid but that's not helping. Thank you for your effort and downvote.

Comment: Then I didn't understand what you're asking, is it not for the distinct/unique country names? Could you give an actual text sample of the JSON with an expected output? What does your current code output, and how does it differ from the desired result?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What I need is indeed a DISTINCT array with country names . Like you could do LINQ filtering in nested data. I don't know how to `select` the country names `where` the deeply nested property `types[0]` equals ``"country".`

Comment: you should do it when subscribing for the data

Comment: @Aravind I agree but I'm not getting the desired result even if I move it to my subscribe

Comment: can u give me a sample full json data i will work on it and give u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want from each entry is the `long_name` values, you can extract them as follows:

```
let long_names = countries
  .map(country => country.address_components.filter(component => component.types.indexOf('country') > -1)  // get relevant components
  .filter(components => components.length > 0)  // filter out any without a country component
  .map(components => components[0].long_name);  // get long name of first country component
```

You can then apply the solutions from [Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960473/3001761) to get the unique values.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way using lodash is:

```
countries=[];
let data = _.find(countries, { types : ['country'] });
countries= _.uniq(countries.push((data.long_name ? data.long_name : ''))) ;
```